# How to access whole double array in or outside loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am writing a program which finds the best answer of equation y=a+b+c (in reality this equation would more difficult, but here is just short example).
The problem is that my sorting code can't get access to whole array in loop.
Is there any way to pass whole array to sorting code?

```
package pkg03;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double a1 = 0;
    double a2 = 3;
    double aZ = 3;
    double b1 = 0;
    double b2 = 3;
    double bZ = 3;
    double c1 = 0;
    double c2 = 3;
    double cZ = 3;

    double aT = (a2 - a1) / aZ;
    double bT = (b2 - b1) / bZ;
    double cT = (c2 - c1) / cZ;

    double a11 = a1 - aT;
    double b11 = b1 - bT;
    double c11 = c1 - cT;
    ciklas(a11, a2, aT, aZ, b11, b2, bT, bZ, c11, c2, cT, cZ);

}
public static void ciklas(double aS, double aE, double aD, double aZS, double bS, double bE, double bD, double bZS, double cS, double cE, double cD, double cZS){
    double z1;
    double a = aS;
    for (z1=0; z1<=aZS; z1++) {

        a = a + aD;
        double z2;
        double b = bS;
        for (z2=0; z2<=bZS; z2++){

            b = b + bD;
            double z3;
            double c = cS;
            for (z3=0; z3<=cZS; z3++){
                c = c + cD;
                double y = a + b + c;

                double[][] masyvas ={
                    {y},
                    {a, b, c}};
```

// Problem is here! Sort code can get only one line of array. So it can't compare the values.

```
    double temp;
    double temp2;
    double temp3;
    double temp4;

    boolean fixed=false;
    while(fixed==false){
        fixed=true;
        for(int i=0; i<masyvas[0].length-1; i++){
            if(masyvas[0][i] > masyvas[0][i+1]){
                temp = masyvas[0][i+1];
                temp2 = masyvas[1][i+1];
                temp3 = masyvas[1][i+masyvas[0].length+1];
                temp4 = masyvas[1][i+(masyvas[0].length)*2+1];


                masyvas[0][i+1] = masyvas[0][i];
                masyvas[1][i+1] = masyvas[1][i];
                masyvas[1][i+masyvas[0].length+1] = masyvas[1][i+masyvas[0].length];
                masyvas[1][i+(masyvas[0].length*2)+1] = masyvas[1][i+(masyvas[0].length*2)];

                masyvas[0][i] = temp;
                masyvas[1][i] = temp2;
                masyvas[1][i+masyvas[0].length] = temp3;
                masyvas[1][i+(masyvas[0].length*2)] = temp4;


                fixed=false;
            }
        }
    }


for(int i = 0; i < masyvas[0].length; i++){
System.out.println(masyvas[0][i] + " = " + masyvas[1][i] + " + " + masyvas[1][i+masyvas[0].length] + " + " + masyvas[1][i+(masyvas[0].length*2)]);

}



            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is probably more complicated than it needs to be. What do you mean by 'best answer of equation y=a+b+c'?

Comment: A sorted equation values from min to max.

Comment: What does 'A sorted equation values from min to max' mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you can't simply pass an array as argument:

```
public void fun (double[][] array){}
```

Or, to put it more precisely, a *value of reference* to that array. This is how it works in Java.

Comment: You mean to write array data to file?